# Using IWA with SAS ExportPackage utility

Tags: sas

**Is it possible to avoid the use of passwords when using the SAS Metadata Batch Export Tool?**

I am building a feature in my STP web app (SAS 9.2, IWA, Kerberos) for auto-exporting metadata items.  As per the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bisag/64088/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003261084.htm), the ExportPackage utility requires credentials either directly (`-user` and `-password` etc options) or via a connection profile (`-profile`).

Logging onto the application server as **sassrv**, the contents of my connection profile are as follows:

```
#Properties file updated on: Thu Mar 12 16:35:07 GMT 2015  !!!!! DO NOT EDIT !!!!!!!
#Thu Mar 12 16:35:07 GMT 2015
Name=SAS
port=8561
InternalAccount=false
host=DEV-SASMETA.somecompany.int
AppServer.Default=A5MNZZZZ.AR000666
AllowLocalPasswords=true
authenticationdomain=DefaultAuth
SingleSignOn=true
```

Running my code however results in the following:

```
44        +%put Batch tool located at: &platform_object_path;
Batch tool located at: C:\Program Files\SAS/SASPlatformObjectFramework/9.2
45        +filename inpipe pipe
46        +   " ""&platform_object_path\ExportPackage"" -profile MyProfile
47        +  -package 'C:\Temp\TestPackage.spk' -objects '/SomeFolder/ARCHIVE(Folder)' -includeDep -subprop";
48        +data _null_;
49        +   infile inpipe;
50        +   input; putlog _infile_;
51        +run;

NOTE: The infile INPIPE is:
      Unnamed Pipe Access Device,
      
      PROCESS="C:\Program Files\SAS/SASPlatformObjectFramework/9.2\ExportPackage" -profile MyProfile  -package 'C:\Temp\TestPackage.spk' -objects '/SomeFolder/ARCHIVE(Folder)' -includeDep 
      -subprop,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=256

The export process has failed.  The native implementation module for the security package could not be found in the path.
For more information, view the export log file: C:\Users\sassrv\AppData\Roaming\SAS\Logs\Export_150427172003.log
NOTE: 2 records were read from the infile INPIPE.
      The minimum record length was 112.
      The maximum record length was 121.
```

The log file was empty.

Presumably my options here are limited to:

1. Requesting the user password from the front end
2. Using a system account in the connection profile
3. Using a system account in the -user & -password options

??

Comment: I've had this same error in DI Studio, see http://i.imgur.com/nTVCgSy.png but I have not solved it. It seems to be a hint here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/jdbcref/59666/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p01t5zmek2f953n1qfntnikm3tfm.htm the file sspiauth.dll must be available to the JVM through system path

Comment: The error above seem to be because JRE is 64 bit, maybe using a 32 bit JRE would solve it. But, I think ExportPackage only work with 32 bit JRE anyways, so the issue might be that sspiauth.dll is not available...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was initially resolved by embedding a username / password in the profile, but now it works by taking the (modified) template profile below, and adding the `host=` / `port=` parameters dynamically at runtime (so can use the same profile in different environments).

IWA is now used to connect to the metadata server!

```
# This file is used by Release Management for connecting to the metadata server
# The host= and port= parameters are provided by the application at runtime
SingleSignOn=true
AllowLocalPasswords=true
InternalAccount=false
SecurityPackageList=Negotiate,NTLM
SecurityPackage=Negotiate
```

An important thing I discovered (not in SAS documentation) is that you can substitute a profile name with an absolute path to a profile (.swa file) in the ExportPackage commmand.

**Edit (one year later):**
As pointed out by @Stig Eide, the error does seem to relate to 32 vs 64 bit JREs.  I also came across this issue in DI Studio today and solved it by copying the sspiauth.dll files as described [here](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2016/10/the-native-implementation-module-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

I verified this some time ago with SAS Technical Support; it's currently not possible.

I entered a SASWare Ballet item for it: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SASware-Ballot-Ideas/Add-Integrated-Windows-Authentication-IWA-support-to-Batch/idi-p/220474

please vote!